# Order objects by occurrences

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code which creates objects of each word (words that are in **wordsArray**) and checks for the number of occurrences of each word and stores this along with each object.

```
var wordOccurrences = { };
for (var i = 0, j = wordsArray.length; i < j; i++) {
        wordOccurrences[wordsArray[i]] = (wordOccurrences[wordsArray[i]] || 0) + 1;
}
console.log(wordOccurrences);
```

This outputs:

```
Object { hello: 1, world!: 2, click: 1, here: 1, goodbye: 1 }
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me with ordering the objects by their occurrences e.g. ascending or descending order. I have tried a few ways but none has yielded the correct results.

The desired output would be something like:

```
world! 2 
hello 1 
click 1 
here 1 
goodbye 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting JavaScript Object by property value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var wordOccurences = { "hello": 1, "world!": 2, "click": 1, "here": 1, "goodbye": 1 }
var sortable = [];
for (var word in wordOccurences)
      sortable.push([word, wordOccurences[word]])
sortable.sort(function(a, b) {return a[1] - b[1]}).reverse()
var result = {}
for(var i = 0; i < sortable.length; i++){
result[sortable[i][0]] = sortable[i][1]
}
```

console.log(result);

Comment: I've accepted your answer (as you've helped) even though i literally answered it 3 mins after posting the question :p thanks anyway

Comment: @NewToCoding haha glad to (kind of) help!

Answer (score 1):

Just take an array for the keys and sort it.

```js
var wordOccurrences = { hello: 1, 'world!': 2, click: 1, here: 1, goodbye: 1 },
    words = Object.keys(wordOccurrences).sort(function (a, b) {
        return wordOccurrences[b] - wordOccurrences[a] || a.localeCompare(b);
    });

document.write(words.map(function (a) {
    return a + ': ' + wordOccurrences[a];
}).join('<br>'));
```

Comment: I solved it myself but will leave an upvote for your help. Thanks :)